# how to generate complete WSDL of a WCF service?

Tags: wcf, wsdl

I have a wcf service that is being hosted as `http://localhost:123/Service.svc`
If I generate the wsdl using `svc path?wsdl`the wsdl gets displayed but that contains only the **wsdl:binding** part which are the exposed operations.

Although that is enough to generate the proxy class but is there any way to get the complete wsdl which has all the metadeta like **wsdl:types, xs:schema , wsdl:message , wsdl:portType**

Answer (score 0):

With .NET 4.5 a new feature was implemented in WCF - Flat WSDL. You can find more information [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/piyushjo/archive/2011/10/05/what-s-new-in-wcf-4-5-flat-wsdl-support.aspx).

In earlier versions of .NET the WSDL contained as you said only wsdl:bindings and references to (another url) schemas etc. That was changed in .NET 4.5 although the original functionality is still available. Single wsdl is accessible with `svc path?singleWsdl` parameter in url.

Comment: I know of no other way to do this. You will have to download the wsdl and all referenced xsds and join them manually.